# SSRS Reports parameters greyed out and not rendering

Tags: reporting-services

In our production environment we have SSRS 2008 R2. When we are trying to access the reports using *http://{ServerName}:{Port}/Reports* then all the parameters are greyed out, and report is not rendering at all. But when we are trying to access the reports using *http://{ServerName}:{Port}/ReportServer* OR using the report builder then its working fine, all the parameters are available and it is rendering the reports. What can be the root cause for this issue? I checked the the processing options and its not Snapshot based.

Comment: The parameters are waiting for a value to assigned to them but that is not happening. Are there any hidden parameters which need to be fed default values?

Comment: No Sourav, they are not hidden parameters.

Comment: Maybe it's an access issue. Check if the service account under which Reporting Services is configure has the appropriate access. You can do this by running the query in dataset using the same service account.

Comment: No luck Saurav, its not access issue as well.